# Android EditText does not work, android:imeOptions="actionNext" android:inputType="phone"

Tags: android, android-edittext, ime

I have tried, and only if I delete `android:inputType="phone"` the keyboard Enter can jump to the Next EditText. I don't know whether there have been some conflicts between `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` and `android:inputType="phone"` .

code :
`AutoCompleteTextView` has `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` and `android:inputType="phone"`, but Enter on the keyboard will not go to the next one.

```
         <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                    android:paddingTop="12dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/fd_28" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/texttitle_phone"
                    style="@style/TextviewRentItem"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dip" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/content_phone"
                    style="@style/TextviewRentItemCon3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/texttitle_phone"
                    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="12dp"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:singleLine="true" 
                    android:inputType="phone"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout0_ll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rect_black_filled_white"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- the second-->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_house"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="12dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/fd_29" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview3"
                    style="@style/TextviewRentItem"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:text="@string/house" />

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/add_rent_manage_house"
                    style="@style/TextviewRentItemCon3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textview3"
                    android:dropDownHeight="90dp"
                    android:hint="@string/default_add_rent_house_remind"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Note: It's ok on Stack Overflow to answer your own question if you solve your own problem, just to make it clearer your problem is solved than an edited-in line buried in your question :)

Comment: i cannot use Answer Your Question ,the web site ask me "Human Verificaition",and I cannot pass it...

Comment: I think the real solution to your problem was adding `android:singleLine="true"`

Comment: As for now, use `singleLine` despite it is deprecated. `android:maxLines="1"` doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

(Answered by the OP in an edit and in comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Problem has been solved. My EditText use **setOnClickListener** , delete this listener event ,that's ok

@xbakesx wrote:

> I think the real solution to your problem was adding `android:singleLine="true"`